# How to validate URLs with express?

Tags: node.js, express, url-validation

I'm looking to validate URLs by whitelisting a certain list which are allowed. I am using a Node.js server with express.js.

I've looked into using the Node.js library "validator", but this means I need access to the full URL that the request was sent from. However, if the user searches for https://localhost:8080/index.html I have found no way of handling that request, so that I can pass it through the validator library and thus accept or reject it.

Comment: Could you clarify the part "this means I need access to the full URL" ? Which option of _validator_ library did you try ?

Comment: Basically, my understanding is with validator you can have a whitelist of OK URLs and check if an incoming URL matches them. So do so I need the URL which was searched for to generate the request. So something like ````validator.isUrl( URL, host_whitelist: [whitelist]) ````. My issue is I can't seem to get the URL of the incoming request if it ends in .html. 
For example if they search https://localhost:8080/index - I can handle that in app.egt("/index") but if they search  https://localhost:8080/index.html then I can't, not can I in app.get("/index.html") as neither are triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so using the NPM package 'express-validator' which contains a whitelist sanitation chain API.

https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers

Comment: Note that the isURL() method of express-validator works only from version 7.0.0